# reading symbian ^3

Tags: symbian

i have a qusetion about reading symbian ^3,i mean how we read ^ in this statement?i didnt see  any where.
i m sorry for my simple question.but i need know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official website:

> `Symbian^3` (pronounced *Symbian three*) - or `S^3` for short - is the latest and greatest version of the Symbian platform.

This pronounciation is consistent with `Symbian^2` and `Symbian^1`.

#### Related links

- [developer.symbian.org - Symbian^3](https://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian%5E3)

---

#### In other contexts

Elsewhere, the character may be pronounced "caret". In C-inspired programming languages, it's usually defined as the *[exclusive-or (XOR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)* operator, usually pronounced "x-or". In logic, a similar symbol `∧` signifies *[logical conjunction (AND)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)*.

In some mathematical context, `^` is often used to denote exponentiation (e.g. [`2^8 = 256` in Google Calculator](http://www.google.com/search?q=2%5E8)). Some of the more mathematically oriented programming languages also use this notation for exponentiation (e.g. Matlab, Microsoft Excel, Haskell, etc).

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/^](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5E)

Comment: IMHO it is confusing when older phones are S60 3rd Edition.